# java access try code block from a separate class

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

Hi i am trying to use an Access data bases within java and i am having a spot of trouble. below i have set up a connection to my database.

```
public class DBAccess {
DBAccess() {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=CFPDB.mdb;";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I need to access the 's' variable form with my gui class in order to check a password:

```
else if(event.getSource() == loginSubmitButton){
        DBAccess loginCheck;
        String selFromTable = "SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = '" + loginUsername.getText() + "'; ";
        loginCheck.s.execute(selFromTable);
        ResultSet retrievedPassword = loginCheck.s.getResultSet();
        String password = retrievedPassword.getString(1);
        String password_entered = loginPassword.getText();
    }
```

But my compiler says it can't find symbol - variable 's'.
Class DBAccess is in a separate file to my gui, but are both in the same package. any help would be great. :)

Comment: To let class share things with the world we have class fields and getters.

Comment: `s` isn't a field, it's a variable that goes out of scope as soon as the object is created. The other issue is that the object is never created, and that you never sanitize your SQL, leaving you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't work like this, each variable has its own scope, indicating where is it defined, where is it prone to be used and when will be collected by Garbage Collector. In general, a good way to remember it at the begining is that variable will only 'live' while inside the nearest brackets {}.

In this case, your 's' variable has a limited scope for the try-catch block, so as soon as that block ends, the s variable is not accessible anymore, you can verify this by trying to compile this code:

```
DBAccess() {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=CFPDB.mdb;";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        s.execute(""); // compiles without problem.
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        s.execute(""); // does not compile.
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    s.execute(""); // does not compile.
}
```

So your best option is to declare s as a class field:

```
public class DBAccess {

    private Statement s;

    DBAccess() {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=CFPDB.mdb;";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
            s = conn.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Statement getStatement() {
        return s;
    }
}
```

And then accessible it via it's getter method. By the way, remember to instantiate your object via its constructor (line 2)

```
else if(event.getSource() == loginSubmitButton){
        DBAccess loginCheck = new DBAccess(); // invoke constructor
        String selFromTable = "SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = '" + loginUsername.getText() + "'; ";
        loginCheck.getStatement().execute(selFromTable);
        ResultSet retrievedPassword = loginCheck.getStatement().getResultSet();
        String password = retrievedPassword.getString(1);
        String password_entered = loginPassword.getText();
}
```

Another option which I don't really recommend (but state here just for you to know) is to declare the s field as public:

```
public class DBAccess {

    public Statement s;

    DBAccess() {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=CFPDB.mdb;";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
            s = conn.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then you can access it the way you wanted:

```
loginCheck.s.execute(selFromTable);
```

Comment: while Matěj Račinský's answer is also correct SEAang's is more concise and well written with explanations to help future viewers of this question. btw thanks to you both :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make field from s, because field exists as long as object owning it exists. The s now disappears when DBAccess constructor finishes. So you want something like this:

```
public class DBAccess {

private Statement s;

DBAccess() {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=CFPDB.mdb;";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
        s = conn.createStatement();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Statement getStatement() {
    return s;
}
}
```

and in your gui class access the s using getter:

```
else if(event.getSource() == loginSubmitButton){
    DBAccess loginCheck;
    String selFromTable = "SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = '" + loginUsername.getText() + "'; ";  //this is vulnerable to SQL injection, use prepared statements, see for example, here https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/
    loginCheck.getStatement().execute(selFromTable);
    ResultSet retrievedPassword = loginCheck.s.getResultSet();
    String password = retrievedPassword.getString(1);
    String password_entered = loginPassword.getText();
}
```